# Maps of Rome, Italy

Tags: maps, rome

Can I get a map of Rome with streets and trains on the same map, so that I know where I am? If I only have a metro map, I do not know the street I will be in.

Comment: Plenty of those in Rome, even your hotel may offer a free one. Google Maps also has both streets and train stations.

Answer (score 8):

On your laptop/mobile phone, Google Maps offers this.

Alternatively, Open Street Maps.  You can download offline maps to use without internet with apps like OSMAnd.

Comment: Google Maps has offline maps, too, though in a somewhat inconvenient way (you select a rectangle on a map, and then they decide for you, how detailed you want this map to be, it is always so nice when really smart people decide everything for you). OSM is mostly preferable, its only major drawback is lack of traffic.

Comment: @bipll indeed and I use that for my work/home areas to save a bit of bandwidth. But being able to download say, all the 'stans when travelling through Central Asia was very useful. OSM was also better than Google in these areas - Murmansk (Russia) for example was about 2 streets on Google back in 2011.

Comment: In Russia you only need to travel 10 km from Moscow to discover where OSM is better than Google. :)

Comment: @bipll yep, I basically stopped using it after St Petersburg

Comment: Google stupidly stops labeling streets with their names when you turn on the transit view, seriously detracting from a feature that would otherwise be very useful (unless you're in a place that you already know well, which is more or less antithetical to the purpose of a map).  And their transit database in Geneva is abysmal.  Trams and trains are shown running on the wrong streets, some even in an entirely different part of town.  I suspect petty vengeance for Switzerland's limitations on street view.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other options, if you are in Rome as a tourist the [Roma Pass](https://romevacationtips.com/should-i-get-a-roma-pass/) gives you several days of free bus and metro travel, skip-the-line access to Rome's main attractions, and comes with a handy street, bus and metro map.